# why does my javascript code is not working in HTML block editor of wordpress

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have been trying to run this code for two hours and have always got the same error, i.e., no output but when i preview it before publishing is all good and working fine. I am using the generate theme plugin for my wordpress site i have provided the code below.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Average Grade Calculator</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #333;
        }

        #inputForm {
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 2px solid #333;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
        }

        input[type="number"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 8px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        button {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        button:hover {
            background-color: #555;
        }

        #resultBox {
            border: 2px solid #333;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Average Grade Calculator</h1>

    <form id="inputForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <th>Weight</th>
            </tr>
            <!-- Input fields for grade and weight -->
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" id="grade1" step="0.01" placeholder="Assignment Grade"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="weight1" placeholder="Assignment Weight"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" onclick="addInputRow()">Add Row</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="calculateAverageGrade()">Calculate</button>
    </form>

    <div id="resultBox">
        <p id="result"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
        let rowCount = 1;

        function addInputRow() {
            rowCount++;
            const table = document.querySelector('table');
            const newRow = table.insertRow(-1);

            const gradeCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
            gradeCell.innerHTML = `<input type="number" id="grade${rowCount}" step="0.01" placeholder="Assignment Grade">`;

            const weightCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
            weightCell.innerHTML = `<input type="number" id="weight${rowCount}" placeholder="Assignment Weight">`;
        }

        function calculateAverageGrade() {
            // Initialize variables to store the sum of (Grade * Weight) and the sum of weights.
            let sumGradeWeight = 0;
            let sumWeights = 0;

            // Loop through each grade and weight input and calculate the sums.
            for (let i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
                const grade = parseFloat(document.getElementById(`grade${i}`).value);
                const weight = parseFloat(document.getElementById(`weight${i}`).value);

                // Check if the grade and weight are valid numbers.
                if (!isNaN(grade) && !isNaN(weight)) {
                    sumGradeWeight += grade * weight;
                    sumWeights += weight;
                }
            }

            // Calculate the average grade.
            if (sumWeights !== 0) {
                const averageGrade = sumGradeWeight / sumWeights;

                // Display the result.
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `Average Grade: ${averageGrade.toFixed(2)}`;
            } else {
                // Handle the case where the sum of weights is zero.
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Please enter valid grade and weight values.";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want someone to solve my query immediately, please.

Comment: exactly what error are you getting in the browsers *developer* tools console?

Comment: If it doesn’t work in the rendered version that you should examine the source code of the rendered version (ie using view source in the browser) to see what is different about it.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding `async` and `defer` to your script balise, like this:

```
<script async defer>your javascript code here</script>
```

Comment: Why should they? It won’t do anything, those attributes are only supported when there is a src attribute.

Comment: thank you so much but its not working even doing this

Comment: My bad @Quentin, i thought async and defer attributes worked also with script balise without src attributes